# HTML/CSS - Background color for navigation bar has mysterious black and white bars when placed over another background

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay, background-color

I am having a very mysterious and maddening problem with a navigation bar that changes color on mouse-over. Every time I try to assign the navigation bar to change color on hover, it appears with the correct color but also shows a tiny sliver of white on the left side of the bar and a tiny sliver of black on the right side of the bar. It isn't too noticeable at first, but ultimately it makes it look like the navbar elements are offset by one pixel. Below is an image showing the background color when hovering as well as the black and white mystery bars. The image also shows how there are no mystery bars when I turn off the background color of the body. [image: Proper and glitched colors]

It seems that these mystery bars only appear when I have assigned a background color below the navigation element (whether in the body or the HTML as a whole). But when I remove the background color, the bars seem to disappear. I am unable to find any literature on this problem at all and can't explain why it only happens when there is another color below. I have tried using a background image instead of background color but seem to get the same error either way. Below is my HTML and CSS for reference. Let me know if I have missed any details that may help to understand the issue.

```css
/* basic body */

body {
  /*background-image: url("zSupporting/Imagery/Background_screenshot.png");*/
  background-color: #0e95ef;
  padding-bottom: 7vw;
  width: 98vw;
}


/* (navBAR) Nav Bar Customization */

.navBAR a {
  margin: 0.7vw;
}

.navBAR {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  padding-bottom: 2vw;
  padding-top: 1.5vw;
  width: 98vw;
}

.navBAR ul {
  padding: 0vw;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navBAR ul li {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0vw;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 15vw;
}

.navBAR ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navBAR ul li ul {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 10vw;
}


/* Make list turn yellow */

.navBAR ul li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  background-clip: border-box;
  color: black;
}


/* Change lettering to black */

.navBAR ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
}


/* Make sub-list items visible */

.navBAR ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* Sublist text to stay white */

.navBAR ul li:hover ul a {
  color: white;
}


/* Make sub-list item turn yellow */

.navBAR ul li ul li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}


/* Make sub-list text black */

.navBAR ul li ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SNC_CSS.css">

<div class="navBAR">
  <ul>
    <!-- Home Page List Item -->
    <li class="navBUTTON">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>

    <!-- Mitchshow List Item -->
    <li>
      <a href=#>Mitchshow</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/@MitchShow" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">YouTube Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Brosplay List Item -->
    <li>
      <a href=#>Brosplay!</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/@newsupernotcool" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">YouTube Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- A-discussions List Item -->
    <li>
      <a href=#>A-discussions</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/@adiscussions" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">YouTube Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- SNC Archive List Item -->
    <li>
      <a href=#>SNC Archive</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/@oldsupernotcool" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">YouTube Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- World of Warcraft List Item -->
    <li>
      <a href="SNC_WOW.html">Warcraft</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your posted code reproduce the problem, because I'm not seeing any white bars (mysterious or otherwise)?

Comment: I apologize, as it did not. There was a missing reference to the CSS sheet. The code has been updated and should reflect the issue. You will see a solid blue nav bar that turns yellow when hovered over but you will also see a very thin black strip on the right hand side of the hovered element that shouldn't be there. It occurs both on the main list items and drop-down list items. You will also notice that removing the background color fixes the error for the drop-down list, but not the main list. The problem also persists even with a margin added between the items. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not seeing that issue (in Firefox, on Ubuntu) from 0% to 500% zoom. Is there a particular browser in, or platform upon, which the behaviour shows up?

Comment: It could be a result of the windows operating system, but I am not sure. Just tried firefox and found the same thing. It is incredible subtle, but the right hand side has a single-pixel wide black bar appearing.